# Deep find object in tree, then return object and the path to it through the tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algorithm, recursion

I've written a recursive function to find a given object and the path within that tree, but when I change the target id (over here : if(tree.targetModuleId === 7)) to 10 I got error:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unshift')"

I supposed to get the path: [1,2,5,6,10].

In the end I need the option that no matter what point to point I want to get a route, I need to get an answer what the route is and if not then get []

I would love to get help on the subject, I enclose a code I made.

```js
let nodes = [
  { sourceModuleId: 1, targetModuleId: 2},
  { sourceModuleId: 1, targetModuleId: 8},
  { sourceModuleId: 2, targetModuleId: 3},
  { sourceModuleId: 2, targetModuleId: 5},
  { sourceModuleId: 8, targetModuleId: 9},
  { sourceModuleId: 3, targetModuleId: 7},
  { sourceModuleId: 5, targetModuleId: 6},
  { sourceModuleId: 6, targetModuleId: 10},

];

function toTree(arr) {
  let arrMap = new Map(arr.map(item => [item.targetModuleId, item]));
  let tree = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr[i];

    if (item.sourceModuleId !==1) {
      let parentItem = arrMap.get(item.sourceModuleId);
      
      if (parentItem) {
        let { children } = parentItem;

        if (children) {
          parentItem.children.push(item);
        } else {
          parentItem.children = [item];
        }
      }
    } else {
      tree.push(item);
    }
  }

  return tree;
}

function findInTree(tree) {
  
  if (tree.targetModuleId === 7) {
    let path = [tree.sourceModuleId,tree.targetModuleId];
    return {result: tree, path};
  } 
  if(tree.children){
    for(let i=0; i< tree.children.length;i++){
      let tmp = findInTree(tree.children);
      if (tmp) {
        tmp.path.unshift(tree.sourceModuleId);
        return tmp;
      }
    }
  }  
  else {
     for (let i = 0;i< tree.length; i++) {      
      let tmp = findInTree(tree[i]);
      if (tmp) {
        return tmp;
      }
    }
    return [];
  }
}
let tree = toTree(nodes);
let paths = findInTree(tree);
console.log(paths);
```

Comment: What is the start node and end node? This looks like a graph to me.

Comment: What have you found out by debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in `findInTree`:

- `return []` is not correct: this is a truthy value, and so the caller's `if (tmp)` will be true, and it should not. The data type that your function returns should be consistent. It seems it should be an object with `result` and `path` properties, but then it is inconsistent to have a `return []` in your code. Make that `return null`, so to indicate there is no such object and this value will be falsy, given the expected behaviour for the caller. Move this `return null` out of the `else` block so it also applies for when the `if` block does not execute a `return`.
- In the `if (tree.children)` block it is not necessary to loop over those children as that will happen in the recursive call. Note how you never use `i` in that loop, so it is a waste of time to repeat that body. Just remove the loop.

```
function findInTree(tree) {
  if (tree.targetModuleId === 7) {
    let path = [tree.sourceModuleId, tree.targetModuleId];
    return {result: tree, path};
  } 
  if (tree.children) { 
      // No need to loop. It will happen in the recursive call
      let tmp = findInTree(tree.children);
      if (tmp) {
        tmp.path.unshift(tree.sourceModuleId);
        return tmp;
      }
  }  
  else {
    for (let i = 0;i< tree.length; i++) {      
      let tmp = findInTree(tree[i]);
      if (tmp) {
        return tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return null; // data type consistency
}
```